# iOS: JSON pars error when using return instead of echo in PHP service file

Tags: php, ios, json, echo, afnetworking-2

I have following `HTTP` request with `AFNetworking`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dictionary setObject:@"login" forKey:@"request"];
[dictionary setObject:@"q" forKey:@"userName"];
[dictionary setObject:@"q" forKey:@"password"];

DDLogDebug(@"LoginView - login - Dictionary: %@", [dictionary description]);

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
//[manager.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:true];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
[manager POST:WEB_SERVICE_URL
   parameters:dictionary
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              DDLogDebug(@"LoginView - Success Response: %@", responseObject);
              NSString *success = [responseObject objectForKey:@"success"];

              if ([success isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                  DDLogDebug(@"LoginView - Login successful!");
                  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSegueLoginToTimeLine sender:self];
              }
              else {
                  DDLogError(@"LoginView - Login failed!");
                  [HMXCommonMethods showMessage:@"Kullanıcı adı ya da şifre hatalı" withTitle:@"Hata!"];
              }
          });
      }

      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              DDLogError(@"LoginView - Error Response: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

              NSInteger statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];

              switch (statusCode) {
                  case 500:
                      [HMXCommonMethods showMessage:@"Sunucu hatası nedeniyle giriş yapılamadı!" withTitle:@"Hata!"];
                      break;
                  case 408:
                      [HMXCommonMethods showMessage:@"İstek zaman aşımına uğradı!" withTitle:@"Hata!"];
                      break;
                  case 404:
                      [HMXCommonMethods showMessage:@"Sunucuya erişilemedi!" withTitle:@"Hata!"];
                      break;
                  default:
                      [HMXCommonMethods showMessage:@"Sunucu hatası nedeniyle giriş yapılamadı!" withTitle:@"Hata!"];
                      break;
              }
          });
      }];

[operation start];
DDLogError(@"LoginView - login - request started.");
```

When I response this request in my `PHP` file with following `echo` code it works fine:

```
$response = "{\"success\":\"1\",";
$response = $response . "\"id\":\"" . $id . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"companyid\":\"" . $cid . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"companyname\":\"" . $cname . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"name\":\"" . $name . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"surname\":\"" . $surname . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"email\":\"" . $email2 . "\",";
$response = $response . "\"password\":\"" . $password2 . "\"}";
$stmt2->close();

$log = "Company ID = " . $cid . "\n" .
       "Company Name = " . $cname . "\n" .
       "Company Address = " . $caddress . "\n" .
       "Company Phone = " . $cphone . "\n" .
       "Company Web Page = " . $cwebpage . "\n";

$this->logger->debug("GetUser: Company Info:\n" . $log);
$this->logger->debug("GetUser: Response:\n" . $response);

echo $response;
```

If I change `echo` with `return` I get `JSON pars error 3840`. I have also tried

```
echo json_encode($response)
return json_encode($response)
```

But it didn't work and I got same error. How can I use `return` without `JSON` error?

Comment: In order for this to work you have to echo something to send back through the AJAX request, return does not output something that the AJAX request can read. And why in the world are you hard-coding JSON?

Comment: @jay-blanchard because I know only this way :) what is your suggestion? What is the true way to do this? Build an associative array and echo that maybe?

Comment: No, use PHP's [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Is there any more formal way to respond an `Ajax` request other then `echo`?

Comment: No, you have to echo.

Comment: Jay, add your comments as answer and I will accept it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for AJAX to be able to read output from PHP, PHP has to echo the response. If you use `return` AJAX is not able to read and use the data as it expects to receive one of several text-like data types: XML, HTML, script, JSON, JSONP, or plain text. A `return` does not provide that.

In addition, you should not be forming JSON strings by hand as it can be a complex thing to do with a potential for many syntax errors. Make use of PHP's JSON functions - [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).